# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime When Converting String to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime

**Problem**

I am trying to convert `String` in `DateTime` format and again converted `DateTime` to `String`

**Case # 1**

```
string time = "20120718 00:56:03";
DateTime theTime =DateTime.ParseExact(time,"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);
string convertedTime = theTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

**Case # 2**

```
string time = "20120718 00:56:03";
string CallDate_DBFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(time).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime CallTime = Convert.ToDateTime(CallDate_DBFormat);
string convertedTime = CallTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

In both cases I get the Exception that

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Look at the format you're specifying... then look at the *actual* format of the data.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: `CurrentCulture` is `en`

Comment: @aa003 There are 13 culture name that starts with `en`. Which one exactly?

Comment: Its "en" `<globalization uiCulture="en" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation of `DateTime.ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

In your case #1, they are not. Use `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss` format instead.

```
string time = "20120718 00:56:03";
DateTime theTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time,"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                       DateTimeStyles.None);
string convertedTime = theTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

For case #2, we need to know your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) property. Why?

Because this method uses [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) method with `CurrentCulture`. Here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#fce604498e2f810b);

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(String value)
{
     if (value == null)
         return new DateTime(0);
     return DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Probably `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss` format is not a standard date and time format for your `CurrentCulture` and that's why this method throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.formatexception.aspx).

Comment: `CurrentCulture` is `en`

Comment: What about case#2 ? `CurrentCulture` is `en` I do not want to specify this format `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss` rather want this `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` directly.

Comment: Its "en" `<globalization uiCulture="en" />`

Answer (score 1):

Do like this. You have set invalid format to parse the string into `DateTime` Look at your `DateTime` string format.

```
string time = "20120718 00:56:03";
DateTime theTime =DateTime.ParseExact(time,"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);
string convertedTime = theTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 string time = "20120718 00:56:03";
        DateTime theTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
        string convertedTime = theTime.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");
```