# ParseExact: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#

Even I'm using `ParseExact()` to convert `string` to a valid `DateTime`, I'm getting error:

```
var Y = "2016/07/13";

DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(Y, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var X = (DT - DateTime.Now).TotalDays;
```

Even with `null` in `CultureInfo` I am getting the same error:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Y, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Whats the reason?

Comment: It should be `DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(Y, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`.

Comment: try with correct format: `DateTime.ParseExact(Y, "yyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Even, I m getting same error

Comment: These parsing methods convert strings values of datetime nature to CLR datetime instance. They don't change the formats, however. You should be using `yyyy/MM/dd` which tells framework the format of string date you have passed.

Comment: OK Thanks. It's working

Comment: Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398993/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-when-converting-string-to-datetime & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053887/convert-20121004-yyyymmdd-to-a-valid-date-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a small [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/liqDld).

Because you are specifying your date as a `yyyy/MM/dd`, you should also specify this exact format when trying to parse the date.

```
    var Y = "2016/07/13";

    DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(Y, "yyyy/MM/dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var X = (DT - DateTime.Now).TotalDays;
```

This code snipped should run perfectly with the date format you have specified.

The official documentation on this method can be found over here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

It contains a lot more information and usecases on the matter.